# Load old Ubuntu Linux after fresh Linux Mint install

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, grub2, busybox

I had Ubuntu and time ago I installed Linux Mint.
During installation there was no option for alongside install, so I chose the manual option for the install to empty the partition (mount point /).
After installation was completed now I can launch only the new LinuxMint. 
But how can I load the old Ubuntu?
I tried to load it from Linux Mint Grub2 console, but then, after

```
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
linux /%vmlinuz%
initrd /%initrd%
boot
```

Computer loading just into BusyBox and can not proceed loading (Ctrl+D) because of `/root/dev/console not found` error. `switch_root -c /dev/console / /init` is not working (outputs help message) and `exec switch_root` also does'not work.
So, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the first time i solve this by loading into grub console (`esc` in time of system boot, then `c`) and type `configfile (hd0,msdos6)/grub/grub.conf`.
After i'll take a look at grub.conf and would try to get a solution for how to put a 'load ubuntu' option string into initial grub2 loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot into you Mint install, install `os-prober` and then run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, this should make grub be able to automatically find any other OS that you have installed and update the grub configuration.

Another way would be to [manually edit your grub menu entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive) and add one pointing to your old Ubuntu install.